# Normalisation results in R^2 score of 0 - Lasso regression

Tags: regression, normalization, lasso

I am running a regression analysis on a 7000 row dataset with a train/test split of 70%/30%. I am using one variable `X` to predict a variable `Y`.

- `X` ranges between 300 and 810 (mean 712).
- `Y` is an integer (number of occurrences) ranging between 0 and 20 (mean 0.2).

Without standardisation or normalising `X`, I receive:

```
Train score:  0.082
Test score:  0.077
```

However upon normalising (`X = (X-X.min())/(X.max()-X.min())`), I receive:

```
Train score:  0.0000
Test score:  -0.0001
```

Is there something incorrect about normalising for a Lasso regression? The same applies to standardising the data. Would anyone be able to advise me on the best course of action?

Answer (score 4):

Standardizing/normalizing is generally the right thing to do, but it will make little/no difference with just one independent variable **if you also adjust the regularization strength**.

With more than one independent variable, standardizing assures that the lasso's penalty applies more equally to all the variables.  Without standardizing, a large-scale variable will be penalized less than small-scale ones (because the coefficients will already tend to be small).

In your case, the original model needs a fairly small coefficient on X because its scale is so large, and so you don't receive much penalty from the lasso.  After you standardize, now the model wants a larger coefficient on X, but that means the lasso penalty makes more of a contribution.  That you get an $R^2$ of zero suggests that the lasso penalty is large enough now to push the coefficient to zero, so that the model is just a horizontal line.  If you reduce the regularization strength a bit, you should be able to recover the old model (exactly maybe, with the right adjustment? If I get some spare time I'll look into this).

[Example Colab notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/62701_lasso_dependence_on_scale.ipynb)